# Help identifying part of window sash

Tags: windows, window-frame

we are trying to identify what the beige plastic part of this window sash set up is. We have had a few of the plastic parts break on other windows and are trying to replace them. Our windows are extremely old (40+ years) so we haven’t been able to identify the window manufacturer to narrow down what part this could be either. Any help Is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: 40 years is hardly _extremely_ old. I had smoothly operating original windows in my previous home from 1952. Those look like the sash supports (lift assist springs), though they're usually hidden when the sashes are installed properly. Do your sashes take a lot of effort to operate, or do they feel well balanced?

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with similar issue recently.
Start by look in the corners of the glass, sometimes there are id codes there.

Some manufacturers put id stickers - usually on the top or bottom of the upper sash. For example: https://parts.andersenwindows.com/detail_WindowVintage__vintage.html

Usually with that information you can either call the manufacturer, or you can go to HomeDepot (or any other home improvement store) and have their window guy figure out what part you need.

Finally, you can take the plastic part off and check for part numbers - sometimes they are stamped on the part itself.

Good luck.